# Receiving error - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 4.3.2 try again later

Tags: smtp

I have a service that sends more than 10 emails at a time.

The problem is that it sends only some emails, not all of them and I keep getting the following error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: 4.3.2 try again later
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)`
```

Answer (score 3):

In general SMTP responses with 4.X.X code require a sender (i.e. your service) to retry mail delivery after a while. They are typicaly issued when mail server is overloaded or has connection problems, so it makes sense to retry mailsending later when (hopefully) problem is gone.

SMTP Error 4.3.2 is an SMTP status response specific to Microsoft Exchange Server. It indicates that the recipient’s mail queue on their Exchange Server has been stopped (frozen).

I'm quite sure, that this is not the issue of your code, but rather Exchange is overloaded, misconfigured or some artifical limitations are set for your e-mail account to prevent your from sending e-mails too fast.